# How to turn inputs into event listeners

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener

I just want to turn this JavaScript code below into event listeners:

```
function plot() {
  var f = document.querySelector("#function").value;
  var color = document.querySelector("#color").value;
  var derivative = document.querySelector("#der").value;

  parameters.data[0].fn = f;
  parameters.data[0].color = color;
  parameters.data[0].derivative.fn = derivative;

  functionPlot(parameters);
}
```

To clarify more, the queries: `#der` , `#color` , `#function` are html inputs and I want to use `addEventListener` instead of `.value`.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each selector, adding a `change` listener to each element, where `plot` is the listener:

```
['function', 'color', 'der'].forEach((id) => {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('change', plot);
});

function plot() {
  var f = document.querySelector("#function").value;
  var color = document.querySelector("#color").value;
  var derivative = document.querySelector("#der").value;

  parameters.data[0].fn = f;
  parameters.data[0].color = color;
  parameters.data[0].derivative.fn = derivative;

  functionPlot(parameters);
}
```